How to Display Images from PostgreSQL in Microsoft RDLC Report Using External Image Function in C#?
I'm working on a C# application where I need to display images stored in a PostgreSQL database on a Microsoft RDLC report. The images are stored as byte arrays in the database. I want to use the external image function in RDLC to achieve this. My database is hosted on the Supabase cloud. The Image type from PostgreSQL is bytea and the image type from RDLC is type Text.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;
using Npgsql;

public void LoadReport()
{
    // Assuming you have a connection already established
    string query = "SELECT tenantpics FROM tb_tenant WHERE firstname = 'Thacksin'";

                        using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand(query, cn.conn))
                        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            // Initialize the list of report parameters
                            var rp = new List<ReportParameter>();

                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                if (reader["tenantpics"] == DBNull.Value)
                                {
                                    rp.Add(new ReportParameter("tenantPics", ""));
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    byte[] imageData = (byte[])reader["tenantpics"];
                                    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageData);
                                    string imageDataUrl = $"data:image/jpeg;base64,{base64String}";
                                    rp.Add(new ReportParameter("tenantPics", imageDataUrl));
                                }
                            }
                            reader.Close();

                            // Set the report parameters
                            reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(rp);

                            // Refresh the report
                            reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
                        }
}

However, the image always display like this
I have tried different approaches including changing the configuration in RDLC to external, yet the issue still remains.

I think you should "realize" the images in a separate step; add them to a collection and confirm that part works; then retrieve them in the reporting step.
